# MTCK and MTDO pins initialization on ESP32S3

Tags: esp32, gpio, jtag, programmer

I'm currently working on a project using the ESP32-S3 chip, and I've decided to use MicroPython for my coding. In my project, I have connected GPIO 39 and GPIO 40 to relays for various operations. The ESP32-S3 datasheet designates GPIO 39 as MTCK and GPIO 40 as MTDO, which are typically used for JTAG debugging and programming.

However, I'm not utilizing JTAG programming for my project. My question is, do I need to perform any separate initialization or special configurations for GPIO 39 and GPIO 40, or is it sufficient to initialize them as regular output pins using MicroPython for my relay control?

I want to make sure that my project runs smoothly while making the best use of these GPIO pins. Any insights or guidance on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can initialize these pins as GPIOs.

Comment: Can you expand this answer?